# grep --regexp=: separating multiple patterns via newline character

Tags: grep

Preparation and testing function:

```
echo -e 'q\nd' > patt

cat patt
q
d

echo 'qweasd' | grep --file=patt
qweasd
```

If you specify 2 templates in the file, everything works according to the manual. How to get the same result by dividing one template into parts using a new line symbol?

Or is it an error in the [manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/grep/manual/grep.html#index-patterns-option)?

> -e patterns
>
> --regexp=patterns
>
> Use patterns as one or more patterns; newlines within patterns separate each pattern from the next. If this option is
> used multiple times or is combined with the -f (--file) option, search
> for all patterns given. Typically patterns should be quoted when grep
> is used in a shell command. (-e is specified by POSIX.)

Only the specified method of separation is of interest, not these variants:

```
grep -e 'pattern1\|pattern2'
grep -e 'pattern1' -e 'pattern2'
```

Answer (score 2):

The manual is accurate, but the method isn’t obvious; use a newline in the command line:

```
$ grep -e 'q
> d' <<<"qweasd"
```

That is to say, type `grep -e 'q`, then <kbd>Enter</kbd>, which should cause your shell to display the secondary prompt (`>`  above), and then enter `d'` etc.

Comment: This method works, but is a similar result possible without additional user input, a one-line solution?

I am trying to understand what was meant in the manual, I doubt that the developers meant this method.

Is it possible to insert a new line character in any way without additional user input?

Say, use the ASCII code of a character (with `LC_ALL=C` environment variable) between the lines of the pattern?

But I don't know yet how to insert a character by its code.

Comment: In some shells (including `bash`), you can use a `$'...'` string. So `grep -e $'q\nd' <<<"qweasd`

Comment: Thank you so much! It is very similar to what I expected.

Comment: @nnlkcncff you can use the technique described by roaima; if you’re in a shell script, splitting across two lines works without additional input. The split line can also be copied and pasted as-is, again without additional input.